# TypeError: this.props.onDelete is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

I'm working on an event crud application with react.js and I get this error:

> TypeError: this.props.onDelete is not a function

This is the user interface :
[image]

And this is the error when I click on delete:

[image]

and I get the same error when I click on edit too.

Here is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Event extends Component {
  onDelete = () => {
    // console.log('event ', this.props.event.id);
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.id);
  };

  onEdit = () => {
    // console.log('event ', this.props.event.id);
    this.props.onEdit(this.props);
  };
  render() {
    const { id, eventname, eventdescription } = this.props.event;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{id}</td>
        <td>{eventname}</td>
        <td>{eventdescription}</td>
        <td>
          <button onClick={this.onEdit}>Edit</button>
          <button onClick={this.onDelete}>Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default Event;
```

This is the DisplayEvent.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Event from './Event';
import axios from 'axios';

class DisplayEvent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '', loading: true, events: [] }; // use array here
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/events')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ events: response.data, loading: false });
      })
      // .catch(function(error) {
      //   console.log(error);
      //   this.setState({loading: false});
      // });
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error); this.setState({loading: false}); });
  }

  render() {
    const { events, loading } = this.state; // get events from the state
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Events</h1>
        <table className="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>ID</td>
              <td>Event Name</td>
              <td>Event Description</td>
              <td width="200px">Actions</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {loading ? (
              <tr>
              <td>
              <h1>Loading events...</h1>
              </td>
            </tr>

            ) : (
              events.map(event => {
                return <Event key={event.id} event={event} onDelete={this.onDelete} onEdit={this.onEdit} />;
              })
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DisplayEvent;
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: share the parent component code please !

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: i don't see a declaration for `this.onDelete` in your `DisplayEvent` class

Comment: Should I rewrite this function (which is in the Event.js file) in the DisplayEvent.js file?
onDelete = () => {
    // console.log('event ', this.props.event.id);
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.id);
  };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event` component is being used inside `DisplayEvents` component. 
`DisplayEvents` is passing a prop `onDelete` to `Event`.

Looking at your code, 
value of `onDelete` prop is `this.onDelete` which you haven't defined in `DisplayEvents` which means, undefined is being passed to the child component (something like this : `<Event onDelete={undefined} >`). You can check this by consoling props in `contructor` of `Event` component.

You need to define your function in parent and then pass it as prop to the child.

You can have a look at the sanbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-lumiere-3yply) for reference

Answer (score 3):

```
<Event key={event.id} event={event} onDelete={this.onDelete} onEdit={this.onEdit} />
```

onDelete is not declared in DisplayEvent component

Comment: worth a comment, not an answer

Comment: @A. Moynet Should I rewrite this function : 

onDelete = () => { // console.log('event ', this.props.event.id); this.props.onDelete(this.props.id); };

 (which is in the Event.js file) in the DisplayEvent.js file?